# SelectListItem and linq any and select statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My CarFormat object has Name and Id property. I'm fetching all carformats which ClientId is equal to the one I passing inside method. I'm doing like this

```
 var carFormats = this.carRepository.All()
                .Where(x => x.CarFormat.Any(c => c.Car.Id == someVar.CarId))
                .Select(x=>x.CarFormat).AsEnumerable();
```

this returns me a list of CarFormat objects.

This object has properties `Name` and `Id`. After I add SelectListItem CarFormats as property inside my viewmodel I tried to bind this enumerable list of resources into select list

```
myViewModel.CarFormats = new SelectList(carFormats, "Id", "Name");
```

but I'm getting databinding exception DataBinding: `

> 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection1[[xxxxx,   xxxxxx,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not
>   contain a property with the name   'Name'.

**When I projection to use only first item from the list everything works, except I need this for all objects not just first**

```
myViewModel.CarFormats = new SelectList(carFormats.First(), "Id", "Name");
```

Comment: You are returning a enumerable containing of ReadOnlyCollections perhaps you meant to get the actual cars within the x.CarFormat ? Possibly SelectMany is needed then

Comment: What type is `x.CarFormat` within your linq query. You are using `Any` on it. and later you select it. I'm thinking it's a list of some sort. so your result is a collection of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to

```
 var carFormats = this.carRepository.All()
            .Where(x => x.CarFormat.Any(c => c.Car.Id == someVar.CarId))
            .SelectMany(x=>x.CarFormat).AsEnumerable();
```

to use **SelectMany**

Some resources

- [Linq - SelectMany Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018361/linq-selectmany-confusion)
- [Difference Between Select and SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany)

Answer (score 0):

The property in your class is a single select list item:

```
SelectListItem CarFormats
```

Which is why it works when you call .First() on the collection.

You are trying to set it with a value of multiple items:

```
myViewModel.CarFormats = new SelectList(carFormats, "Id", "Name");
```

Set the property in your view model class to a select list:

```
public SelectList CarFormats { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missing a .ToList()

myViewModel.CarFormats = new SelectList(carFormats.ToList(), "Id", "Name");